# Java Rest - send parametrized List using GET method

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to send a List by GET method.

Here is my Server side:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<User> getUsers(){
    return managment.getUsers();
}
```

And my client side:

```
public static void getUsers(){
    try {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
        Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);




        WebResource webResource = client
                .resource("http://localhost:8080/Serwer07/user");

        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .get(ClientResponse.class);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }

       List users = response.getEntity(List.class);          
       User user = (User) users.get(0);  //cannot cast
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have problem with cast from Java Object to User. How can I send this List ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [GenericType](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/GenericType.html).

```
List<User> users = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   .get(new GenericType<List<User>>() {});
```

**UPDATE**

`ClientResponse` also overloads [getEntity](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.1.5.1/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/ClientResponse.html#getEntity%28com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType%29) to accept `GenericType`s.

```
List<User> users = response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<User>>() {});
```

Comment: Thanks for Your help. I have not tested the first way but the second one works great.